# Error authenticating user: FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-admin

I am trying to get going with firebase (auth only) in a node.js server but I am running into errors even getting started.

I believe I am following the Google docs exactly for their section "Add Firebase to a server" here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup . Additionally I've read every stackoverflow that pops up in the first few pages of Google search and multiple tutorial sites for firebase-admin + nodejs. Yet cannot seem to get past what seems to be a simple step here.

The specific error I get is:

```
Error authenticating user: FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
```

When I try the following (again trying to matchup to what the docs show):

**.env**:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="firebase-svc-acct.json"
```

(where firebase-svc-acct.json is the service account key for the project obtained as per those same google docs under "Initialize the SDK in non-Google environments")

**index.ts** (node server entry):

```
...
import { initializeApp, applicationDefault } from "firebase-admin/app";
...
initializeApp({
 credential: applicationDefault(),
});
```

**AuthController.ts** (temporary testing, wired up with express router that is not shown here for brevity, trust me it gets here):

```
...
import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
...

loginFirebaseTest = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
const { email, password } = req.body;  
const auth = getAuth(); // <------------------ Error is thrown here
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    console.log(
      "Successfully authenticated user:",
      userCredential.user.uid
    );
    res.status(200).json({ message: "User login successful" });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error authenticating user:", error);
    res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid credentials" });
    res.send();
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the result of `initializeApp()` in a variable and passing that to `getAuth()`? Eg `const app = initializeApp(...)` and `const auth = getAuth(app)`

Comment: @Phil I've not - I've only seen that mentioned when using multiple apps in the linked doc. I most likely should have put that my controller implementation is largely from their auth specific doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth which calls getAuth() without a parameter.

Comment: I'd say this is potentially a timing thing. That or the admin API doesn't behave like the web API when storing a reference to the default app. It does not hurt to be specific about which app you're using, even if there's only one

Comment: Wait, where are you importing `getAuth()` from?

Comment: @Phil I just tried it by "export const defaultFirebaseApp.." the initialize bit in index.ts (server). In the controller it throws a typescript error: 
"Argument of type 'App' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirebaseApp'.
  Property 'automaticDataCollectionEnabled' is missing in type 'App' but required in type 'FirebaseApp'"

If I try to bypass with "as any" and run it fails when it gets hit with "Error authenticating user: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProvider')". 

I'm not sure this is a valid approach.

Comment: @Phil In controller: "import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";" (I will edit OP to show that).

Comment: There's your problem. You can't use the web API in your Node.js app

Comment: Thank you so much that is hard for new-to-firebase-folks to get just from those docs and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users doesn't show the import! Do you have any idea where to import it from for node/server use?

Comment: Last comment before I inevitably post my own answer based on Phil's help. I think the flow is not quite captured clearly in the docs but looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74194542/5117487 now with context from Phil the whole paradigm appears to be user gets the token from Google in the client then bases that to node where is verified with verifyIdToken instead. I wouldn't have thought this to be the case because than the app specific config (note: note the svc acct json) seems to have to be exposed in the UI but seems to be just the way things are done with firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discovered in comments to the original question I was just thinking about firebase completely wrong. Unlike is common when you bake your own auth you won't be passing the email + password over to firebase and handing back a token. The client does that directly to firebase.

So in the backend instead you just start accepting/checking the token - you don't need a login endpoint and you would do that with firebase-admin in nodejs (firebase/auth is for the front end).

Getting into how to authenticate in specific gets outside of the scope of the issue presented here but I found https://www.toptal.com/firebase/role-based-firebase-authentication to do a decent introduction.